# Time delay for DateTime.Now value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I wrote the method in controller like,

```
public ContentResult GetServerTime()
{
   return Content(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

I need to set the **time delay for the return value** is it possible? I am new to MVC.

Comment: What is a _"time delay for the return value"_?

Comment: I access the getserverTime().I dnt want to immediate response.need some time to get the return value.

Comment: i guess you are looking for something like 'Thread.Sleep' ?

Answer (score 0):

As Athiban says, a Thread.Sleep(1000) would delay the response for 1 second.